# Python - how to make non blocking terminal where every one second serial link sends packet

Tags: python, serial, terminal

I can write this in C#, but now i learning python and I don´t know how program this.

I want to make simple terminal where serial link sending every one second packet... In non-blocking way. In C# I would use a timer for this task...
For example serial link still sending word "one" until I type "two"  to terminal and hit enter. And then serial link sending "two"... But always terminal line is available for typing...

Answer (score 1):

[Pyserial](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial.html) can be set to none blocking by use of the **write_timeout** argument in the opening command.  This is documented in the API [here](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html)

If getting a valid timeout value is causing issues (i.e. the data is so long it either times out or becomes noticeable to the user) then I would use the [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) module to create a background task to do the send and a [queue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-in-python/) to link it to the input.

The main loop of the program:

- Waits for the user to enter data
- Performs any validation on that data
- Put the valid data on a first-in first out (FIFO) queue

The background thread sets up the serial port and goes into a never ending loop:

- Waits till data is present on the queue
- Sends that data over the serial line

You would obviously need to handle any errors and decide how to end the program cleanly (close serial port and end the thread).  This could be done by checking for a specific entry from the user or handling the ctrl-c exception.